# The universal covering group of a symmetry group

Tags: quantum-mechanics, group-theory, lie-algebra, representation-theory, topology

In Weinberg QFT Vol.1, it says one can enlarge the symmetry group $H$ to the universal covering group $C$ such that one obtains a trivial cocycle or $C$ is simply connected whereas $H$ is not. I get the mathematical meaning of the statement. I wonder whether this also requires $C$ being an extended symmetry of the system somehow though I thought $H$ is the largest symmetry group of the system. I am kind of confused here how can one further extend the system invariant under the action of the universal covering group unless one define the action of elements beyond $H$ being trivial.

Comment: It's a general principle that we must consider the  *projective representations* of $H$, which are often precisely the linear representations of $C$, see [this Q&A of mine](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/203944/50583)

Comment: The post of @ACuriousMind is more complete than this one of mine (http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/96045/), but it's nonetheless closely related and might be useful to you even though it doesn't directly answer your questions.