# Relation between projective representations, connectivity of a group manifold and number of equivalence classes of paths

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebra, representation-theory, topology, spin-statistics

The projective unitary representations of a multiply-connected group $G$ is defined as $$U(g_1)U(g_2)=c(g_1,g_2)U(g_1g_2)$$ where $c(g_1,g_2)$ is phase. Reading various articles, and this [old post of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/96045/idea-of-covering-group/96060#96060), it appears to me that the topological connectivity of a multiply connected group $G$ determines the number of inequivalent projective representations in the Hilbert space i.e., the number of values $c(g_1,g_2)$ can take. And different inequivalent projective representations will be charecterised by different values of $c(g_1,g_2)$ for the same elements $g_1$ and $g_2$.
For $\textrm{SO}(3)$, as I guess, $c$ takes two different values $\pm 1$.

**Question** From the fact that a “$n$-”ply connected group has $n$ different equivalence classes of paths, I would like to understand how does it lead to $n$ different values of $c$.

Comment: Why do you say that it is difficult to find out the projective reps of $SO(3)$? Or rather, what do you mean by difficult here?

Comment: I have edited the question which now I think addresses your point.

Comment: I explain the classification of projective representations in [this Q&A of mine](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/203944/50583). Non-simply connected (but still e.g. semi-simple with $H^2(\mathfrak{g},\mathbb{R})=0$) groups are case two - projective representations of (the identity component of) a non-simply connected group are in bijection to linear representations of its simply connected universal cover - or also just to linear representations of its algebra. I'm actually not sure *what exactly* you're asking in this question, especially with the "difficult".

Comment: @Acuriousmind: I think I will edit question 2 later. But what do you have to say about 1 and 3?

Comment: For 1, read my post - projective representations are linear representations of central extensions, and being non-simply-connected means that there is a central extension - that to the simply-connected universal cover.. 3. doesn't make much sense to me - of course SU(2) has projective representations - it's just that every such representation already comes from a linear representation of it(because SU(2) doesn't have central extensions, as it is simply connected).