# Do the spinor transformation matrices form a matrix representation of the corresponding Lorentz group?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, dirac-equation, spinors

Suppose $\Psi$ is a Dirac spinor, then let the transformation matrix $S$ be defined as usual: $\Psi'=S(\Lambda)\Psi$, where $\Lambda$ is the Lorentz transformation matrix.

Then the questions is: for two Lorentz transformations $\Lambda_1$ and $\Lambda_2$, do $S(\Lambda_1)$ and $S(\Lambda_2)$ obey $$S(\Lambda_1)S(\Lambda_2)=S(\Lambda_1\Lambda_2)$$ and $$S(\Lambda)S(\Lambda^{-1})=I~?$$

Answer (score 8):

They form a complex [projective representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_representation) in which

$$S(\Lambda_1)S(\Lambda_2)=c(\Lambda_1,\Lambda_2)S(\Lambda_1\Lambda_2)$$

where $c(\Lambda_1,\Lambda_2)$ is a number.

For an arbitrary group, the $c(\Lambda_1,\Lambda_2)$ for its complex projective representations will in general be complex numbers. But in the case of the Lorentz group, complex projective representations can always be chosen to have $c(\Lambda_1,\Lambda_2)=\pm 1$.

See the Wikipedia articles on [Projective Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_Hilbert_space) and [Wigner’s Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_theorem) to begin to understand why projective representations (and not just ordinary representations) are relevant in quantum mechanics.

In some cases the projective representations of a group are equivalent to the ordinary representations of its [universal covering group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_group#Universal_covering_group). For more about this, see [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/96045/idea-of-covering-group).

Answer (score 6):

No. For example, if $Λ$ is a 180-degree spatial rotation, then $S(Λ)^2 = -I \ne I = S(Λ^2)$.